# How to Include custom tokens in the user register welcome mail

Tags: 8, users, tokens

Is it possible to use custom tokens in the default user regitration welcome mail? I need to pass variables from a custom module. Is the solution to create a token in the custom module and include it into the mail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user mail templates can be found at `example.com/admin/config/people/accounts`. The welcome mail for instance looks like this:

> [user:display-name],
>
> A site administrator at [site:name] has created an account for you.
>   You may now log in by clicking this link or copying and pasting it
>   into your browser:
>
> [user:one-time-login-url]
>
> This link can only be used once to log in and will lead you to a page
>   where you can set your password.
>
> After setting your password, you will be able to log in at
>   [site:login-url] in the future using:
>
> username: [user:name] password: Your password
>
> --  [site:name] team

As you can see there are already many tokens used.

Furthermore, Drupal does not distinguish between core tokens and those of modules. So if a textfield allows you to use core tokens (like this one), you can also use any other token. If you create a custom token, you will be able to use it in the mail. BUT, you must keep in mind that this mail template only has access to a select set of tokens (click the *Browse tokens* link below the textarea):

```
Current date    current-date    Tokens related to the current date and time.
Current page    current-page    Tokens related to the current page request.
Current user    current-user    Tokens related to the currently logged in user.
Random  random  Tokens related to random data.
Site information    site    Tokens for site-wide settings and other global information.
Users   user    Tokens related to individual user accounts.
```

When working with tokens, each module can define which tokens it handles (The `$data` array passed to [`Token::replace()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Utility!Token.php/function/Token%3A%3Areplace/8.2.x)). In this specific case, it only gets the `user` entity of the created user. Apart from that, several global tokens are always available, these are `Current date`, `Current page`, `Current user`, `Random` and `Site`.

So your custom token must be provided within the `user` or `site` type.

Comment: Thank you @Neograph734 !

The information that only tokens of the type user or site are allowed was the final hint.

Comment: That's not 100% correct. To be exact, the user is the only non-global data provided for those mails, what you can use is that plus all tokens that are defined as globally available, like current-date, current-page and so on as provided on that output

Comment: @Berdir, you are right. My goal was to explain that node and other entities are not available. I'll change the answer.

Comment: @Berdir, Is it better like this?