# Can i add my custom user field to a user mail template?

Tags: forms, users, emails

I added a custom user field (`/admin/config/people/accounts/fields`) with machine name *field_about_user* to my D9.5 site (yes i know, it needs updating...).

Now i tried to add that field to the Mail template *Admin (user awaiting approval)*
by guessing: [user:field_about_user]
But that's obviously wrong.

Do i have access to other variables than the default ones described in the help text at all?
If so, how?

EDIT:
From [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/226591/how-to-include-custom-tokens-in-the-user-register-welcome-mail) i understand that yes, there are some more. But only variables (=tokens?) of type *user* and *system*.

Now what's not clear to me is:

1. I don't see the mentioned  *Browse tokens* link. Would that added by the token module that i don't have? Or is it just not available in D9.5?
2. As i can't browse for the Token: Would a token for my field be of type *user*? Or some other type? If it's available in *user*, how does it look given above field name? Is a token for it available via core tokens, or do i need the token module?